# How do I can show Django rest nested comments for products?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I created nested comment for my project. I have my model and Serializer. I want to when I retrieve a product for showing product's details the product comments show as well. how do I can do this?
this is my code:

```
#models.py

class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,blank=True, related_name='replys')
    body = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user} - {self.body[:30]}'

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)
```

#serializers.py

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['id', 'category', 'name', 'slug', 'image_1',
                  'image_2', 'image_3', 'image_4', 'image_5',
                  'description', 'price', 'available', 'created', 'updated']
        lookup_field = 'slug'
        extra_kwargs = {
            'url': {'lookup_field': 'slug'}
        }


class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['id', 'user', 'product', 'parent', 'body', 'created']
```

#views.py

```
class RetrieveProductView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    lookup_field = 'slug'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown your ProductSerializer but if you [follow the example](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships) it really should work:

```py
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    comments = CommentSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['name', '...', 'comments']
```

Comment: I edited my question and added product serializer please check it again

Comment: So when you add the `comments = CommentSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)` and field `comments` top your meta fields this should work, right?

Comment: excuse me do you have experience of working with django rest_auth package???

Comment: Sorry no never heard about django-rest-auth but from a quick glance I see I really should use this, thanks for pointing it out!!!

Comment: after that do you mind answering my another question about rest_auth?? sorry I'm really new to django.